# jquery id selection change class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
$('#sidebar ul li ul li').click(function () {
        var ids = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#ids').addClass('active');
        $('#ids').parent('ul').parent('li').addClass('has-sub active');
        alert(ids); // Will alert the id if the element has one    
    });
```

I didn't understand why this is not working. `alert` gives me the id of the `li` element but the 2 lines before it don't work I mean these 2:

```
$('#ids').addClass('active');
$('#ids').parent('ul').parent('li').addClass('has-sub active');
```

Where is the problem? Am I missing something?

[image]

Comment: `'#ids'` is literally the string `#ids`. It has no relation to your variable. Why are you trying to construct a selector out of the `id` attribute of an element? Wouldn't that selector match the `this` element once again? Or are you storing something you shouldn't be in the `id` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@IshanJain @RoryMcCrossan @j08691 @EliantenHolder thank you for your response. Jquery doesnt help to solve this problem but this helper worked.

```
public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{

    public static string ActivePage(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper,string controller, string action)
    {
        string _classValue="";

        string _currentController = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue.ToString();

        string _currentAction = htmlHelper.ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue.ToString();

        if (_currentController == controller && _currentAction == action)
        {
            _classValue = "active";
        }
        else if (_currentController == controller && action.Equals(""))
        {
            _classValue = "has-sub active";
        }
        else
        {
            if (action.Equals(""))
            {
                _classValue = "has-sub";
            }
        }

        return _classValue;
    }
}
```

and this is from my layout page

```
<li class="@Html.ActivePage("Order","")">
              <a href="javascript:;" class="">
                  <span class="icon-box"> <i class="icon-dashboard"></i></span> Sipariş Açma

                  <span class="arrow"></span>
              </a>
              <ul class="sub">
                  <li class="@Html.ActivePage("Order","Index")"><a class="" href="@Url.Action("Index","Order")">Sipariş</a></li>
                  <li class="@Html.ActivePage("Order","orderProduct")"><a class="" href="@Url.Action("orderProduct","Order")">Ürün Sipariş</a></li>
                  <li class="@Html.ActivePage("Order","orderCloth")"><a class="" href="@Url.Action("orderCloth","Order")">Kumaş Sipariş</a></li>
                  <li class="@Html.ActivePage("Order","orderAccessory")"><a class="" href="@Url.Action("orderAccessory","Order")">Aksesuar Sipariş</a></li>
              </ul>
          </li>
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to concatenate your variable like:

```
$('#' + ids).
```

`$('#ids')` is looking for an element with the ID of `ids`. And as Blender noted in the comments, why are you doing it this way? The element you're clicking on could be referred to as simply `$(this)` or `this`. To me it might make more sense to do:

```
$('#sidebar ul li ul li').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').parent('ul').parent('li').addClass('has-sub active');
});
```

And you might also be able to replace `.parent('ul').parent('li')` with `.closest('li')`, but I'd need to see the HTML structure to be sure.

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Are you getting any errors in the console? Can you create a jsFiddle.net example?

Comment: ok I updated the question when I clicked grids for example the menu is closing. it shouldn't be closed. when I wrote its id manually into javascript code it stays opened.

Comment: Sorry but the picture isn't going to help, you'll need to post a complete code example. And as I mentioned before, a jsFiddle should be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You are taking the `id` of the current element to concatenate together a selector. Instead, you can use the `this` keyword within the handler and use it as a reference to the clicked element. Try this:

```
$('#sidebar ul li ul li').click(function () {
    $(this).addClass('active').closest('li').addClass('has-sub active');  
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain why it doesn't work. Errors? Unexpected behaviour? There is no reason this should not work, given the info in your OP.

Comment: I dont know the reason because there is no error when I write it by giving its name manually like this
$('#general').addClass('active');
        //$('#general').parent('ul').parent('li').addClass('has-sub active'); 
it is ok but when I get the id it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

`ids` is a variable which holds the id of clicked element. and in your code:

```
$('#ids').addClass('active');
$('#ids').parent('ul').parent('li').addClass('has-sub active');
```

You use `ids` as a string. This is not correct way. You should replace `$('#ids')` with `$('#' + ids)`.

Try this:

```
$('#' + ids).addClass('active');
$('#' + ids).parent('ul').parent('li').addClass('has-sub active');
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean to apply the new classes to the ids in the variable ids? If so you are currently applying those to elements that have the id of 'ids'. You should use the following selector: `$('#'+ids).`